# Change font awesome Icon colour on success of post

Tags: jquery, css

I am wanting to change the icon color of fa heart to red or the green as follows 
I attempted to use the following but its still staying the green color on the screen does anbyody have any ideas if I am attempting the correct approach.

Green Color Not Favouried : 007c7a
Pink Color Favouried : f7296a

> $(".btnRemoveFave").find('.fa-heart').css('color', '#007c7a');

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".btnAddFave").click(function () {
                      var productId = $(this).data("product-id");
                     $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/dynamic/Favourite.aspx/AddToFavourites",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ 'productId': productId }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            $(".btnAddFave").find('.fa-heart').css('color', '#f7296a');

                            alert(response.d);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d);
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>


<script>  

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".btnRemoveFave").click(function () {
                    var productId = $(this).data("product-id");
                    var customerId = $(this).data("customer-id");
                       $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/dynamic/Favourite.aspx/RemoveFavouriteByCustId",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ 'custId': customerId, 'productCode': productId }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            $(".btnRemoveFave").find('.fa-heart').css('color', '#007c7a');

                            alert(response.d);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d);
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Most likely, the icon itself is generated content. Make sure to always define the color on the icon element itself and then have the CSS for `::before` or `::after` say `color: inherit`…

Comment: I am not sure how I would do that is their any way of changing it in the <i> like how I am doing

Comment: Once you do that, changing the `<i>` tag using JS will work.

Comment: It does not currently work (presumably), because the color is set directly on the generated content (e.g. `::before` or `::after`) so changing the color on its parent will have no effect (and setting CSS properties on generated content via JS requires writing a `<style>` tag into markup, which is much more complicated than setting a `style` attribute, the way jQuery’s `css` function does).

Comment: @rogue1nib. Your code is working, check it https://jsfiddle.net/r726bf6o/1/ . I've added setTimeout to 2nd button of 2seconds, after 2seconds it will change the color.

Comment: @Shiladitya strange its not working on button click i check my db and the code is returning all corect values for the fact if its been removed or not etc. Will debug futher and see

Comment: @rogue1nib . Color changes on button click https://jsfiddle.net/r726bf6o/2/

Comment: @Shiladitya that works but once it is red then needs to go green  thanks

Comment: @rogue1nib Can you update the jsfiddle that I posted in the last comment. Will work on that and share answer with you.

Comment: @Shiladitya when my page renders it renders a span around the button <span id="ctl00_BodyContentHolder_lblfavourite-471110"> could that be the reason that its not working in code ?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153142/discussion-between-rogue1nib-and-shiladitya).

Answer (score 1):

FontAwesome uses a `:before` pseudo element to create the icons, and you cant select pseudo elements - they are not part of the DOM.

A different approach would be to create a class for the "favourited" style, and then add the class...

```
$(".btnRemoveFave").find('.fa-heart').addClass('faved');
```

Comment: my .net pages adds a span around the button of the form  <span id="ctl00_BodyContentHolder_lblfavourite-YLXG20"><button class="btnAddFave" id="btnAddFave_YLXG20" type="button" value="Add To Favourites" data-product-id="xxx" data-customer-id="xxx"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="color: rgb(0, 124, 122);"></i> </button></span>
Is it possible the span is making the code not find the class.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/r726bf6o/3/

```js
$(".btnRemoveFave").find('i.fa-heart').css('color', '#007c7a');
$(".btnAddFave").find('i.fa-heart').css('color', '#f7296a');

$('.btnRemoveFave').wrap('<span id="ctl00_BodyContentHolder_lblfavourite-471110"><span>');

$('button.btnRemoveFave').click(function(){
  $(this).find('i.fa-heart').css('color', '#f7296a');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnAddFave">
  <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
</button>
<button class="btnRemoveFave">
  <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
</button>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @rogue1nib I've added an answer based on last query.

Comment: i dont need the span to be gen i am thinking its the span causing my code not to find the button some reason ?